# mysql how to query where ROUND(AVG(`row`)) equals

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a query which selects a bunch of "items" and an average rating given by customers for that item. it looks like this:

```
SELECT `items`.`itemid`,
       `items`.`name`,
       `items`.`address`,
       `items`.`suburb`,
       `items`.`latitude`,
       `items`.`longitude`,
       `reviews`.`comment`,
       Round(Avg(`reviews`.`rating`), 0) AS avg
FROM   `items`
       RIGHT JOIN `reviews`
               ON `items`.`itemid` = `reviews`.`itemid`
GROUP  BY `items`.`itemid`;
```

now, this works and i get all the information about an item and its average rating.

what I want, is to add a

```
WHERE avg ='3';
```

where that 3 is a selected value so i can search "all items with an average rating of 3" etc.

where avg ='3' doesn't work. i was just wondering if there is a way to do this? using PHP even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use having clause to filter results from aggregate function

```
SELECT `items`.`itemid`,
       `items`.`name`,
       `items`.`address`,
       `items`.`suburb`,
       `items`.`latitude`,
       `items`.`longitude`,
       `reviews`.`comment`,
       Round(Avg(`reviews`.`rating`), 0) AS avg
FROM   `items`
       RIGHT JOIN `reviews` using (`itemid`)
GROUP  BY `reviews`.`itemid`
HAVING Round(Avg(`reviews`.`rating`), 0) = 3
```

Demo using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8d41/2)

Comment: this could be correct but it returns "Missing value in the form!"

Comment: that seems like a problem with values you're submitting,  I'd say ask a new question about that

Comment: i fixed it by adding ";" to the end, it throws a syntax error at "HAVING Round(Avg(`reviews`.`rating`), 0) = 3"

Comment: remove the semicolon after group by; have modified the join clause as well

Comment: `HAVING avg = 3` is enough, no need to re-calculate